# How to delete a document found by a search in the FaunaDB?

Tags: go, faunadb

I can get a searched document as following golang code:

```golang
ret, err := client.Query(f.Get(f.MatchTerm(f.Index("label_search_by_externalID"), externalID)))
```

Then, I tried to delete a searched document as similar manner as follow:

```golang
ret, err := client.Query(f.Delete(f.MatchTerm(f.Index("label_search_by_externalID"), externalID)))
```

But, this code occurs an error:

```
Response error 400. Errors: [delete](invalid argument): Ref expected, Set provided.
```

I'm confused, by the API document, both **Get** and **Delete** request Ref for a document as param, and MatchTerm returns a Set, not Ref.
Then I have 2 questions.

1. How can I get the document Ref which the result of the search?
   Is there any way to get the document ref from the search result with Index like **RefCollection** for collection, for example like **RefIndex** as follows?

```golang
ret, err := client.Query(f.Delete(f.RefIndex(f.Index("label_search_by_externalID"), externalID)))
```

2. Why my code for getting search result document works well? Is there more good coding for getting search result document?

Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get will only return 1 result.  If you have multiple values returned from this index search you will have problems.  I would suggest the function Paginate(). This will return a set of results, which you can then map over and execute other functionality, such as a get() or delete().  I would strong suggest you look at the following tutorial (https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/tutorials/indexes/pagination).

This is pseudo code to delete a page of documents found.  You can adjust the page size either up or down:

```
Map(
  Paginate(Match(Index("label_search_by_externalID"), true)),
  Lambda("X", Delete(Var("X")))
)
```

Comment: Hi John! I can delete it with your suggested way! Thank you!